# Stacked bar plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I have an R data frame of this form: (first, second, ... are row names; A, B, ... are col names)

```
              A   B   C    D  E
 first        30  0   0    0  0
 second       0   20  120  0  0
 third        0   40  100  0  0
 fourth       0   0   0    30 60
```

What I want ggplot() to do is plot a bar graph with the row names on the x axis and row sums on the y axis and those row sums should be color-stacked by the column head categories and be with number labels, so like this for the above data:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'colour stacked'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add rownames as a variable in your data frame, and transform your data to long format so ggplot can handle it. Something like this is close to what you mean I think:

```
yourDataFrame %>% 
    mutate(Label = rownames(df)) %>% # add row names as a variable
    reshape2::melt(.) %>% # melt to long format
    ggplot(., aes(x = Label, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
        geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
df %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = 'x') %>%
  pivot_longer(-x) %>%
  filter(value > 0) %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, levels = c('first', 'second', 'third', 'forth'))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = forcats::fct_rev(name), y = value, x = x, label = value)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=value)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

data:

```
structure(list(A = c(30L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 20L, 40L, 0L
), C = c(0L, 120L, 100L, 0L), D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 30L), E = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("first", "second", 
"third", "forth")) -> df
```